# [Vue warn]: Cannot find element: #app while logging in user in firebase/firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, firebase-authentication

When I call signIn function on the click of a button, firebase sign in service runs and the user gets logged in successfully and I've alerted a message inside `then` function. After that on the console it displays,

```
[Vue warn]: Cannot find element: #app
```

Now, when I refresh the page, the message goes from the console thereafter.
So what is the reason that it displays that message while logging user in for the first time?

```
signIn(){
               
 firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.email, this.password).then(()=>{
       alert("logged in")
    }).catch(err=>{
        this.error = true
        this.errorMsg = err.message
        })
      }
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="icon" href="<%= BASE_URL %>favicon.ico">
    <title><%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title %></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>
      <strong>We're sorry but <%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title %> doesn't work properly without JavaScript enabled. Please enable it to continue.</strong>
    </noscript>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <!-- built files will be auto injected -->
  </body>
</html>
```

main.js

```
import Vue from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import router from "./router";
import store from "./store";
import Vue2Editor from "vue2-editor";
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import "firebase/auth"

Vue.use(Vue2Editor);

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(()=>{
    new Vue({
      router,
      store,
      render: (h) => h(App),
    }).$mount("#app");
})
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you are calling signIn() method before the app is created. And thats the reason of the warning.

Try calling the method inside created(), I think the warining will disapear.